# Error al crear un Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql

Al momento de ejecutar el comando: **php artisan migrate** obtengo el siguiente error en mi ultima migración:

[image: Error migración]

Creo que tengo el orden correcto al momento de ejecutar las migraciones, mi orden de creación de migraciones está compuesto de la siguiente manera:

2021_04_26_190548_create_articulos_table.php (se ejecuta OK)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nombre', 100);
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->integer('stock');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

2021_04_27_142337_create_tipo_articulos_table.php (se ejecuta OK)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tipo_articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nombre', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

2021_04_27_154731_add_field_articulo.php (se ejecuta OK)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('tipoarticulo');
    });
}
```

2021_04_27_160220_add_foreign_articulo.php (Falla ejecución)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('tipoarticulo')->references('id')->on('tipo_articulos');
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel usas?

Comment: Laravel Framework 8.38.0

Comment: Entonces el error es muy simple, los tipos de datos no se corresponden, las llaves primarias se están creando como bigint y tu declaras las llaves foráneas como int, entonces pasa esto: `$table->integer('tipoarticulo');` a esto: `$table->unsignedBigInteger('tipoarticulo');`

Comment: Recomiendo siempre cheques la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Exacto, además desde Laravel 7 hay notación diferente para la creación de claves foráneas: $table->foreignId('tipoarticulo')->unsigned()->nullable()->references('id')->on('tipo_articulos')->onDelete('cascade');

Comment: @FabianM tu sintaxis no termina de ser del todo correcta, te sugiero revises la implementación de dicho método

Answer (score 0):

¿No sería más conveniente borrar y volver a crear la tabla con los valores de comienzo y no irlos agregando en cada migración?

En todo caso podrías crear dos migraciones nuevas con los siguientes métodos

Migración 1

```
public function up(){
    Schema::dropIfExists('articulos');
}

public function down(){
    Schema::dropIfExists('articulos');   
}
```

Migración 2

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nombre', 100);
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->integer('stock');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tipoarticulo');
        $table->foreign('tipoarticulo')->references('id')->on('tipo_articulos');
    }
}

public function down(){
    Schema::dropIfExists('articulos');
}
```

Comment: Dar de baja la tabla anteriormente creada en la migración